# Navigationbar height increase and decrease in ios

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uinavigationbar, ios10

i am new to swift and here i have a requirement i want to increase/ decrease navigation bar height as per requirement

**Here:** To increase navigationbar height i used this lines

```
extension UINavigationBar {

  override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 99.0)
    }
}
```

this lines are working .but how to decrease navigationbar height

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample project.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just simply set the frame for your `navigationBar`?

```
let size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 100)
navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
```